# Validating data from mysql query in express.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a post api which i want to validate data before inserting it into data base .
I want to check if the customerCode from the body exists in database or not .
this is my code but it always returns " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

```
app.post('/CreateCustomer', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err
        const params = req.body
        connection.query('SELECT CustomerCode FROM Customers WHERE CustomerCode = ?', params.CustomerCode, (err, rows) => {
            // connection.release() // return the connection to pool
            

            if (rows[0] == undefined) {
                connection.query('INSERT INTO Customers SET ?', params, (err, rows) => {
                    connection.release() // return the connection to pool
                    if (!err) {
                        res.send(`Customers with the record ID  has been added.`)
                    } else {
                        console.log(err)
                    }

                    console.log('The data from beer table are:11 \n', rows)

                })
            } else {
                res.send("Csutomer Code Already taken!")
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use a unique index in mysql than to rely on a select for checking for existence.

Comment: How are you sending request body? are you sure that CustomerCode is defined in the request body?